# delayed chained payment

Tags: paypal, payment, chained

Can anyone tell me how to automatically execute a delayed payment (let's say it's 5 days after the primary receiver receive the payment) in a chained payment manner? The key is automatic execution, not having to manually approve and pay the secondary receiver. Please illuminate with some sample code.

I have used "actionType" => "PAY_PRIMARY" so that primary receiver get money.

But how can I code so that secondary receiver get money?

Answer (score 2):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5289760/218413) for the solution. Basically you just need to execute an `ExecutePayment` operation with the `payKey` within 90 days to send the payment to the secondary party.

Answer (score 0):

actionType is PAY_PPRIMARY
you then trigger this payment within 90 days.
Its delayed but not time-elapsed.

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf

Comment: I'm sorry but can you elaborate? I did specify actionType as PAY_PRIMARY. Then how do I trigger the delayed second payment to the secondary receiver in 5 days automatically?

Answer (score 0):

well may be its too late but it will help someone in future for sure.
As we integrated paypal delayed chained payment, you can set a primary account in which all the amount will go and you can also set secondary account in which account will be transfered once they approved by primary account holder.

```
    string endpoint = Constants_Common.endpoint + "Pay";
     NVPHelper NVPRequest = new NVPHelper();
     NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.requestEnvelopeerrorLanguage] = "en_US";
    //NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.actionType] = "PAY";
    //the above one is for simple adoptive payment payment 
     NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.actionType] = "PAY_PRIMARY";
    //the above one for deleayed chained payment
     NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.currencyCode] = "USD";
     NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.feesPayer] = "EACHRECEIVER";
     NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.memo] = "XXXXXXXX";
```

Now we have to set primary and secondary receivers:

```
    //primary account
        NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.receiverListreceiveramount_0] = TotalAmount;
        NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.receiverListreceiveremail_0] = "XXXx.xxxxx.com";
        NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.receiverListreceiverprimary_0] = "true";
        //secondary accounts
        NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.receiverListreceiveramount_1] = (somemoney out of total amount);
        NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.receiverListreceiveremail_1] = "xxxxx.xxxx.com";
        NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.receiverListreceiverprimary_1] = "false";
        NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.receiverListreceiveramount_2] = (somemoney out of total amount);
        NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.receiverListreceiveremail_2] = x.x.com;
        NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.Pay2.receiverListreceiverprimary_2] = "false";
```

Don't forget that you have to give a valid paypal account while using delayed chained payment.
    Now you get your pay_key which you have to use to execute your payment whithin 90 days so that other secondary receivers get money.
    Here is the working code:

```
    String endpoint = Constants_Common.endpoint + "ExecutePayment";
    NVPHelper NVPRequest = new NVPHelper();
    //requestEnvelope.errorLanguage is common for all the request
    NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.requestEnvelopeerrorLanguage] = "en_US";
    NVPRequest[SampleNVPConstant.ExecutePayment.payKey] = "your pay key";
    string strrequestforNvp = NVPRequest.Encode();
    //calling Call method where actuall API call is made, NVP string, header value adne  end point are passed as the input.
    CallerServices_NVP CallerServices = new CallerServices_NVP();
    string stresponsenvp = CallerServices.Call(strrequestforNvp, Constants_Common.headers(), endpoint);
    //Response is send to Decoder method where it is decoded to readable hash table
    NVPHelper decoder = new NVPHelper();
    decoder.Decode(stresponsenvp);
    if (decoder != null && decoder["responseEnvelope.ack"].Equals("Success") && decoder["paymentExecStatus"].Equals("COMPLETED"))
    {
    //do something
    }
```

Hope it will help someone.